# Word to Warn of Danger of Usage

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns, adjectives

I need a term or word to refer to something which is very powerful but if used naïvely will cause great harm.

I could say: "This is a [noun], use with care." or: "Use this with care it is [adjective]."

My example would be Fusion, it's powerful... but you better know what you're doing.

Comment: Sounds like [The Force](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Force_(Star_Wars)).

Comment: In  a text that thing is simply called "dangerous","to be used with caution", or "to be used with extreme care". If it's one word to put on the physical thing it's usually "danger", "warning", "caution" or "beware of" depending on the situation. You can also draw a triangle with an exclamation mark inside.

Comment: What's wrong with *powerful,* again?

Comment: @AndrewLeach powerful doesn't imply the negative effects of naïve use will cause great harm. For example, I'm using a *powerful* computer right now.

Comment: Great question, I believe **there is no such single word**, surprisingly. Phrases like "Pandora's box" are sometimes relevant.

Comment: *hazardous* is the word often used in this context.

Comment: I think "hazardous" is a good word to use, but an alternative could be "a double-edged sword", to imply that it has benefits to equal its hazards.

Comment: @JoeBlow I think for me `Pandora's Box` may be the best answer. I think it best summarizes what I'm trying to say. If you wanna give that as an answer I'll accept. I just don't think that there's a word that exactly fits the situation. If only `Radioactive` had this as a secondary meaning...

Comment: Use great care and be warned for the consequences when opening Pandora's Box.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about PANDORA'S BOX?

It's often used in English for this sort of thing -- depending on the exact shade of meaning you want.  Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

If you want a word to warn of danger of usage, I would recommend *dangerous* or *perilous*. From Merriam-Webster online,

> [**Dangerous**](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/dangerous) *adj.*
>
> involving possible injury, harm, or death : characterized by danger

and

> [**Perilous**](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/perilous) *adj.*
>
> full of danger